# Multiplexing more than 2 signals using Altera's LPM

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, quartus

How can I use `busmux` more than two input in Quartus? It seems I can use `LPM_MUX` instead, but I can't understand how to use it. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 0):

While using `lpm_mux`, you need to drive 3 signals (+ clock for pipelined usage):

- `data` port, which consists of `LPM_SIZE` buses, each `LPM_WIDTH` wide,
- `sel` signal, which selects one of the input buses, `LPM_WIDTHS` wide,
- `result` port, which is `LPM_WIDTH` wide.

`data` and `sel` are both inputs, `result` is output port. Values of `LPM_SIZE`, `LPM_WIDTH` and `LPM_WIDTHS` can be set using `defparam` clause.